# Layout deslizable Android

Tags: android, android-layout, xml

[image: Idea]

Esta es básicamente la idea que tengo como  puedo hacer que el layout inferior (abajo de la imagen)sea deslizable mediante el desplazamiento lateral del dedo. Tengo pensado que en este juego que estoy desarrollando permita al jugador invertir mediante dinero o valores escogiendo primero uno de los dos layouts y despues llevando acabo la inserción de datos que el layout solicite.

Adjunto código:`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/saldoLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/saldoTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/saldo"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/letra"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/activityStockLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/saldoLinearLayout"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="7dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/activityStockLinearLayoutLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/activityStockValue_textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="10.763,30"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/activityStockName_textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:text="IBEX 35" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/activityStockIniciales_textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="^IBEX"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/activityStockApertura_textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:text="Valor Apertura:" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/activityStockValorTop_textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Maximo:" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/activityStockValorLow_textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Minimo:" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/activityStockValorAnoTop_textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Maximo Anual:" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/activityStockValorAnoLow_textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Minimo Anual:" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/activityStockLinearLayoutRight"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/activityStockLogoLinearLayoutRight"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/ibexlogo"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/graphLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/activityStockLinearLayout"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/graph" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>`
```

Comment: Facil hermano, con un Viewpager swipeable jajaja , lo mismo que utilizamos para los Navegadores Tabs. Ves que deslizamos para la izquierda o derecha en un Tab , pues lo mismo, solo que no le pondrias titulos, solo el Viewpager

Comment: lo probare segun salga de la oficina gracias por la ayuda ;D

Comment: De nada tocayo, asi que trabajas y te da tiempo de hacer un juego, madre mia jaja, animos!

Comment: Estoy de becario en una empresa por las mañanas y a las tardes sigo con el desarrollo de el proyecto de fin de curso, que es este juego.... Ando algo ocupado XD. Rápidamente y sin perder mucho el hilo del post tu por casualidad no habrás realizado autenticaciones OAuth en alguna APP que hayas hecho no? Gracias y una vez este delante de mi ordenador emplearé las mejoras que me comentaste 

Comment: Si , con Firebase o el API REST de la empresa , para tareas te quedaría perfecto Firebase , si gustas escríbeme a mi correo eduardo@eduardoricardez.com para no hacer spam aquí.

Answer (score 1):

Justo como dice Eduardo Ricaderdez te quedaria perfecto 
y justo aqui tienes un ejemplo de como poder ponerlo en practica saludos.
[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](http://www.tutorialsface.com/2015/09/android-viewpager-simple-tutorial-sliding-screens/)